# Android: Attempting to Instantiate a class

Tags: java, android, instantiation

I am still new to Java programming in general and I'm now trying to tackle instantiating, and encountering some problems. I have tried to make as simple as possible way to test this, however my program will force close.

*My Class

```
public class InterfaceScreen extends Activity implements testInterface1 {
TextView tv1, tv2;
String String1 = "I ate a pizza!";
String String2 = "sleeping......";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_interface_screen);
    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);   

    //Attempint to create a new InterfaceScreen (which is an animal by the way....)
    InterfaceScreen myAnimal = new InterfaceScreen();

    //now telling our animal to eat and sleep
    myAnimal.eat(String1);
    myAnimal.sleep(String2);

}
public void eat(String text1) {
    tv1.setText(text1);
}

public void sleep(String text2) {
    tv2.setText(text2);
}
```

}

*My interface screen, again making it as easy as possible.

```
public interface testInterface1 {

    void eat(String text1);
    void sleep(String text2);
}
```

XML for my activity

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context=".InterfaceScreen" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Log Cat output

```
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.generaljavalearning/com.example.generaljavalearning.InterfaceScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557):     at com.example.generaljavalearning.InterfaceScreen.eat(InterfaceScreen.java:33)
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557):     at com.example.generaljavalearning.InterfaceScreen.onCreate(InterfaceScreen.java:28)
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
02-28 16:03:36.621: E/AndroidRuntime(2557):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: "InterfaceScreen" is the name of my class.  "testInterface1" is really my interface.

Comment: Please post the stack trace, along with the XML for your `Activity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onCreate`, you already operating inside an instance of `InterfaceScreen`. It's called `this`. You don't need to create a new instance.

Instead of

```
myAnimal.eat(String1);
myAnimal.sleep(String2);
```

just say

```
this.eat(String1);
this.sleep(String2);
```

or even better

```
eat(String1);
sleep(String2);
```

Also, variables typically start with a lowercase letter: `string1` and `string2`. Classes start with an uppercase letter.

The `NullPointerException` was happening because your new instance wasn't getting correct `tv1` and `tv2` references. In Android, we don't make instances of our `Activity`s.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do here but you don't instantiate an `Activity` like you do a normal Java class. So this is wrong

```
InterfaceScreen myAnimal = new InterfaceScreen();
```

You would just call something like

```
eat(String1);
```

It looks like you would possibly want a normal Java class called something like Animal. Then you could instantiate it like you are trying to do and set/get properties. But just for what you are doing you can do by just calling the method.